# RPM to get X11 headers for RHEL

Tags: xorg, rpm, rhel-5

What is the best single rpm to install to get a complete set of X11 headers on Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5.x?

My guess is Xaw3d-devel (assuming that the dependencies also get installed).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personally I'd go with `yum groupinstall 'X Software Development'`